# Is it possible to extract JavaScript function implementation in java using ScriptEngine

Tags: javascript, java, scriptengine

Suppose I have a JS function,

```
function sum(a,b){
  return a+b;
}
var a = sum(10,20);
```

Now if I execute this with ScriptEngine like below,

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
engine.eval(inputString);
Bindings bindings = engine.getBindings(100);
for(String s:bindings.keySet()){
    System.out.println(engine.get(s)); 
}
```

It is always giving the evaluated values like `a = 30`. So my question is it possible to get `function sum(a,b){...}` also from the ScriptEngine.

There is a way to get encodedSource as

```
InterpretedFunction.class.cast(bindings.get("sum")).getEncodedSource()
```

But is there something to get decoded source?

Answer (score 0):

Casting the eval'ed engine into an `Invocable` will expose you to many useful functions for this:

```
private Invocable getInvocableJSEngine() throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    engine.eval(script);
    return (Invocable) engine;
}

...

getInvocableJSEngine().invokeFunction("sum",a,b);
```